# Using JUnit 5 to test .java files in different folders

Tags: java, junit5

I need to use JUnit 5 to test all `Foo.java` in different folders. All these `Foo.java` have implemented the same method interfaces (but with different method implementations). Suppose they don't belong to any package (i.e., there is no `package xxx;` on top of each file)

```
dir1
  - Foo.java
dir2
  - Foo.java
dir3
  - Foo.java
```

I used IntelliJ IDEA + JUnit 5 + JDK 17 and have created a standard JUnit project.
I already have a JUnit test that works for each **single** `.java` file (cuz they all implemented the same set of methods with identical method signatures/APIs), if I put any individual `.java` file in the project `src` folder.

Yet, the problem is, all these directories `dir*` and `.java` files are not related to this project; they are stored **somewhere else outside** of the JUnit project's path.
In this case, how can I automatically test **all** of these `.java` files?

(I guess I need to programmatically traverse these files, compile them to `.class`, and use Java Reflections to instantiate objects using the `.class` file, then proceed the tests as usual. I wonder whether this is the way to go, or if there is any better approach.)

Comment: So you're saying that a *single* unit test class can be run against each one of those Java classes? What package(s) are they in? Are all three `Foo` classes in the same package (i.e. it's 3 different implementations with the same FQCN)? What build system are you using?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I've edited the question for clarifications. Thanks.

Comment: This setup is highly unorthodox and you'll have a hard time making it work with a traditional build system. It sounds like your best bet is to have a shell script that iterates over the directories, compiles the `Foo.java` and then invokes Java with the compiled version of the test (and its dependencies like Junit) and the output directory of that compilation on the classpath. But files like this being in the unnamed package (not having a `package` declaration might actually make the compilation hard. Is this meant to verify student submissions for a given programming task?

Comment: @JoachimSauer "Is this meant to verify student submissions for a given programming task?" yes, something like that.